# Will json_encode always return same result for an associative array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to calculate the md5 value of a string which was the result of `json_encode` of an associative array which was received from mysql.

Can I get the same md5 value if the data has not been changed?
Or I must sort the keys of associative array by some rules so as to make sure that the `json_encode` function can return the same string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sort the array before or the md5 will be different. 
Consider using krsort function.

Follow [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) link for more info.

Comment: Correct answer. Wonder by you have a preference for `krsort` over `ksort`?

Comment: Correct, but may not be the use case. If the array keys where entered in the same order, then for the same values the json_encode value will be the same. Because the question mentioned that it is an array from a MySql query result, then the keys will be the same, and in the same order, only the values may be different, so while it will not hurt, it is just an unnecessary sort.

Comment: @trincot I depend of the nature of the array. A simple ksort for a simple array and krsort for a nested array (an array of array).

Comment: @RonDadon, in theory an SQL sort order *might* be different when there is no `order by` clause (or one that is not specific enough) as tables grow. At a certain point, the database might change the execution plan, yielding a different order than before.

Comment: @MorganGil, the `r` in `krsort` is not for `recursive` but for `reverse`

Comment: @trincot It will change the order of the rows maybe, not the columns, so the keys of the resulting associate array returned from the query should always be in the same order.